# Login into a Form using Python3. Not able to do it with python-requests

Tags: python, forms, authentication, python-requests, urllib

The login form of this page was changed a while ago and while i was able to login before i can't suceed now. The page in question is: http://www.racingpost.com/ and the one i think holds the new login form is https://reg.racingpost.com/mpp/sign_in.sd

I Think part of the login is done then externally and there may be when the problem comes. I've tried using python requests and passing in the headers the parameters but i can't get over it.

I'm no expert in html so it is possible that the parameters passed to requests are not the correct ones. Can somebody help me?

Regards,
Albert.

Comment: What have you tried? I can see that a POST request is being made to https://edeveloper.mppglobal.com/interface/Mpp/eDeveloper/v8/eDeveloper.json.svc/UserAuthenticateByEmail with a payload like {"EmailUserInfo":{"EmailAddress":"your@email.com","UserPassword":"yourpassword"}}. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes. I tried also that with no success. I've also tried to include the referer and so on but even checking on the network information sent i think more headers need to be added apart of these.

Comment: In fact the only option to made it work has been with some automated soft, in that case i used selenium, but i wanted something directly on the code instead of using any web browser enabled tool. Many Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do it i've found is using selenium, which is not ideal for me as i wanted to do it directly on the code, but in any case it can be accomplished in the following way:

```
driver = self.driver
# Uncoment to enable login
driver.get( "https://reg.racingpost.com/mpp/sign_in.sd" )
driver.find_element_by_id( "input-email").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id( "input-email").send_keys("email@address.com" )
driver.find_element_by_id( "input-pwd").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id( "input-pwd").send_keys("passw0rd" )
driver.find_element_by_id( "button-sign-in").click()
time.sleep(8)
driver.get('http://www.racingpost.com/horses2/cards/card.sd?race_id=636248&r_date=2015-10-28#raceTabs=sc_' )
#time.sleep(10)
driver.execute_script( "window.stop()")
print(driver.page_source.encode( 'utf-8'))
```